# IMG in 1st TD leads to bottom-align of contents in 2nd TD

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 TDs , the 2nd TD has `valign=top` but it's content is displayed UNDER the contents in 1st TD .

What could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net because using your description it works great http://jsfiddle.net/qNF94/

Comment: Could you add your HTML/CSS? Otherwise, *I* have no idea.

Comment: Oh thank you guys i have found the problem , there was an imported CSS which aligned everything to the bottom :s

Answer (score 0):

Some imported CSS file aligned everything to the bottom ...

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

Comment: To avoid having this problem in the future, you should use a tool like Firebug (Firefox) or Developer Tools (Chrome/IE) to see what CSS is being applied to the problematic element.

Comment: I am using chrome , but the css was so messed i missed it